# Why am getting NA while adding 64 minutes to the time in r?

Tags: r

I am getting **NA** while adding time to minutes.why?

```
time1<- as.ITime(paste0("07:47:00")) +as.ITime(paste0("00:",64, ":00"))
```

It is giving NA instead of **08:51:00** .why?

Comment: because 64 is `NA` it should be `time1<- as.ITime(paste0("07:47:00")) +as.ITime(paste0("01:",04, ":00"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`paste0("00:",64, ":00")` yields `"00:64:00"` which  is not possible as a time. You could add the minutes as a number multiplied by seconds.

```
library(data.table)

time1 <- as.ITime(paste0("07:47:00")) + 64*60
# [1] "08:51:00"
```

You also could do

```
as.ITime(paste0("07:47:00")) + as.ITime(64*60)
```

since

```
as.ITime(64*60)
# [1] "01:04:00"
```

Comment: Thank you.It is simple but i could not figure it before.

Comment: @Magie Welcome. Consider to accept one answer please.

Comment: How to convert 64 minutes to 01:04:00 in this format?

Comment: I have tried with converting like this ``` as.ITime(paste0("00:",64*60,":00"))``` It is  giving  **NA** again

Answer (score 0):

Using base R, you can do :

```
format(as.POSIXct("07:47:00", format = "%T") + 64 * 60, "%T")
#[1] "08:51:00"
```

Or using `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
hms('07:47:00') + seconds_to_period(minutes(64))
#[1] "8H 51M 0S"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for giving different type of answers. As i following as.ITime method. I'll go with jaf.sf answer.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
time1<- as.ITime(paste0("07:47:00")) +as.ITime(paste0("01:",04, ":00"))
```

64 minutes are 1 hour 4 minutes.